# Where can I find open etymology databases?

Tags: data-request, language, api

Are there any open and directly accessible, freely available, English etymology dictionary databases like the one used by [online etymology dictionary](http://etymonline.com)?

It could be accessible either directly via database clients (e.g. `mysql`) or available as a `.sql` dump file.

I'm aware that there are many free online English dictionaries that define the word and explain its origins, particularly [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com) (or Google search itself with `define:word` search syntax) and [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org), that offer offline access to their databases mainly for mobile phones, as is the case with Google.

I seek further information on the subject and want to access or download and deploy such databases on a local database server.

Answer (score 2):

One option is the [XML data dump](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/) from Wiktionary ([link to a recent one](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/20141129/)).

> A complete copy of all Wikimedia wikis, in the form of wikitext source and metadata embedded in XML. A number of raw database tables in SQL form are also available. 
>       These snapshots are provided at the very least monthly and usually twice a month.

There is also an API and file download based on the Wiktionary data, but I don't know how comprehensive: http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~demelo/etymwn/

> The Etymological Wordnet project provides information about how words in different languages are etymologically related. The information is for the most part mined from Wiktionary. The semi-structured data is turned into a machine-readable etymological database that also incorporates some additional manually added etymological relationships.